# Асинхронная обработка "POST" запроса. Фреймворк iohttp

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Скажите пожалуйста, как организовывать обработку входящих запросов(асинхронных), использую фреймворк "aiohttp". Имеется всего один обработчик запросов:

```
async def receive_update(request):
    """ """
    hand_serv(await request.json()) # создается экземп.класса, в котором происходит дальнейшая обработка запроса 
    
    return web.json_response({'ok': True})
```

Как сделать, чтобы каждый из поступивших запросов мог обрабатываться параллельно т.е. чтобы вновь пришедший запрос не дожидался окончания действий происходящих в `hand_serv(await request.json())`, а мог там же параллельно обрабатываться? Возможно ли это вообще?

Внутри `hand_serv()`:

````
class HandlerServer:
    """ """
    def __init__(self, request_json):
        self.request_db = RequestsDb()
        self.hand_req_db = HandlerReqDb()
        self.teleg = Telegram()
        self.req = request_json
        self.chat_id = self.req["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        self.text_message = self.req["message"]["text"] if "text" in self.req["message"] else ""
        self.select_comand()

    def start_command(self):
        """ """
        user_exist = self.hand_req_db.user_exist(self.chat_id)
        if not user_exist:
            add_user = self.request_db.add_user_info(self.chat_id)
            if add_user:
                self.teleg.select_iphone(self.chat_id)
        else:
            status_take_iphone = self.hand_req_db.get_status_take_iphone(self.chat_id)
            if status_take_iphone:
                self.teleg.get_picture_chang_iph(self.chat_id)
            else:
                self.teleg.select_iphone(self.chat_id)

    def any_iphon_command(self):
        """ """
        user_exist = self.hand_req_db.user_exist(self.chat_id)
        if user_exist:
            stat_take_iphone = self.request_db.set_status_take_iphone(self.chat_id)
            set_id_iphone = self.request_db.set_id_iphone(self.chat_id, self.text_message)  # пользователю присваивается id_iphone
            if stat_take_iphone and set_id_iphone:
                self.teleg.get_picture_chang_iph(self.chat_id)

    def get_wallpapers_command(self):
        """ """
        user_exist = self.hand_req_db.user_exist(self.chat_id)
        stat_take_iphone = self.request_db.set_status_take_iphone(self.chat_id)
        if user_exist and stat_take_iphone:  # если пользователь есть в БД и он уже выбрал модель своего айфона
            self.teleg.send_message(self.chat_id, "Секундочку, Ваши обои тоже ждут встречи с Вами \U0001f929")
            self.teleg.send_photo(self.chat_id)

    def stop_command(self):
        """ """
        del_user = self.request_db.del_user(self.chat_id)
        if del_user:
            text = """Если Вы вновь захотите воспользоваться ботом, нажмите - "Начать" """
            self.teleg.get_start_butt(self.chat_id)
            self.teleg.send_message(self.chat_id, text)
            


    def select_comand(self):
        """ """
        if self.text_message == "/start":
            self.start_command()

        if self.text_message in self.hand_req_db.get_iphone_list():
            self.any_iphon_command()

        if self.text_message == "Получить обои":
            self.get_wallpapers_command()

        if self.text_message == "Изменить модель iphone":
            self.teleg.select_iphone(self.chat_id)

        if self.text_message == "Начать":
            self.start_command()

        if self.text_message == "/stop":
            self.stop_command()
```
````

Comment: Сделать `hand_serv` асинхронным?

Comment: Получается да, сделать асинхронным

Comment: Покажите код `hand_serv`, а то с комментария в коде я не совсем понимаю как он работает

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, вставив туда код. Пишу телеграм бота, без использования "Telebot" и тд. def select_comand(self) решает что делать дальше, обработав сообщение текстоевое , которое пришло в запросе.